# Redirect route at global.asax.cs

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Is there a way for me to make everyone that access `localhost/subscribe` to be redirected to `localhost/subscribe.aspx` by using a rule inside `global.asax.cs` or should I redirect from action?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following code should work for you:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.RawUrl.ToLower().EndsWith("subscribe")) 
    {
        Response.Redirect("subscribe.aspx");
    }
}
```

Or inside **Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute** method if you going to use also Session for verifications

Comment: I don't think having custom string evaluation on every request is the best solution.  Customer Routes, as suggested by Dallas are a better solution.

Comment: Agree, but it is just a different simple solution

Comment: I'd ratter go with the simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Phil Haack has an example of [redirecting using routes](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx)

However for one url the easiest solution is probably to redirect from the action.

Comment: I don't want to use third party libs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are redirecting a virtual url to a physical file, it's pretty easy to do this in the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
     RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Key", "Home", "~/Public/Pages/Default.aspx");
}
```

In this case,

> http://www.example.com/Home

redirects to

> http://www.example.com/Public/Pages/Default.aspx

Just an FYI, doing this doesn't redirect on the client, it redirects on the server, meaning that the server doesn't return a 302 with the new address, it simply sends back the content you're directing it to.

This is also nifty for adding variables, like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("MainPublic3", "Public/Pages/{PAGE}/{CHILD}", "~/Public/Pages/Pages.aspx");
```

These can then be accessed in the code behind like this:

```
string page = Page.RouteData.Values["PAGE"];
string child = Page.RouteData.Values["CHILD"];
```

We use this for everything where I work, of course we are switching to MVC :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its a bit late, but this would've helped me a lot back then.